# How can I get my min and max function to print my error message properly?

Tags: python, max, min

This is the prompt we were given to find the function needed:

A function that prompts the user for the minimum value and returns it
to the calling statement. Function to also deal with range checking to
make sure that the minimum value provided is greater than 0

Here's my code below however it doesn't print out the error message when I enter a minimum value higher than the maximum value.

```
def get_min():
       return int(input("What's your minimum value?"))

def min_Check(get_min):
    if (get_min >= 0):
      return print("ERROR. Minimum should be greater than 0")
else:
      return get_min

def get_max():
        return int(input("What's your maximun value?"))

def max_Check(get_min):
   if (get_max <= get_min):
    return print(f"ERROR. Maximum value must be greater {min}")
else:
    return max 

min_value = get_min()
max_value = get_max()
get_check1 = min_Check(get_min)
get_check2 = max_Check(get_min)
```

Comment: You need to make smaller changes to you code between test: Do small changes, then test. Only when the code does what you expect (not necessarily what you want, but what you expect), should you add more code. Each code change should be small. Start with deleting all code relating to `max`, then work on `min_Check`. Pass is a content values, until you get it to work. Before you connect it to `get_min`. Then work on the `max` code.

Answer (score 1):

note the difference :
1- you make a wrong condition in min_check function 
2- you don't use () when you use the output of the two get function in conditions

```
def get_min():
    return int(input("What's your minimum value?"))
def min_Check(get_min):
    if (get_min() <= 0):
        return print("ERROR. Minimum should be greater than 0")
    else:
        return get_min
def get_max():
    return int(input("What's your maximun value?"))
def max_Check(get_min):
    if (get_max() <= get_min()):
        return print(f"ERROR. Maximum value must be greater {min}")
    else:
        return max
min_Check(get_min)
max_Check(get_min)
```

Comment: Although correct, when answering a question you should explain your reasoning so the person that initially posted the question can understand what you did. Don't simply tell them to note the difference between your code and theirs

Comment: thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: No worries, you made some nice changes to the code to make it more readable and optimised

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things in your code that need fixing:

1. Both max_Check and min_Check have the `else` statement outside the
   function, I don't know if this was a copy paste error but you need
   to fix that.
2. You never pass get_max as an argument for max_Check so it will never
   do the `if` correctly because it is missing an argument. You should
   have gotten an error for that.

Comment: I still need to call the max and min checks at the end correct?

Comment: Also `get_min` and `get_max` are terrible names for variables.e.g. would you ask “what is the get_min?“ or “get would you like fries with that?”

Comment: Yes, you need make the calls you already make. The only difference is that when calling max_Check you need to pass both the minimum value and the max value

Comment: Alright thank you guys